# Set a CPT slug as a base name for all the taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, url-rewriting, 404-error, taxonomy

I'm looking for help because I tried to look on the web for a solution but I can't to solve my 404 page issue.

I'm bulding a custom WordPress plugin for my photo club. This plugin wants to display portfolio for each members.
Picture are classified by :

- Author (photographer)
- Color
- Theme (the category)

I created a custom post type `ms_photo_porfolio` and the 3 taxonomies :

- `ms_photo_author` for the taxonomy Author
- `ms_photo_color` for the taxonomy Color
- `ms_photo_cat` for the taxonomy Theme

I want to set the slug `/photographies/` of the custom post type as a **basename** for these 3 taxonomy slugs.

These URLs actually work :

- thewebsite/photographies/
- thewebsite/themes/
- thewebsite/couleurs/
- thewebsite/membres/

I created 4 pages, and created the template files as index pages.

However I want to transform these URLs to :

- thewebsite/photographies/
- thewebsite/photographies/themes/
- thewebsite/photographies/couleurs/
- thewebsite/photographies/membres/

I set the parent page Photographie for last 3 pages but these pages leads to a 404 page. It's vital to keep a hierarchical structure for a good SEO.

I know there are a lot of subjets about this issue but I'm confused and lost. I don't want to install a plugin in order to fix my problem (security issues).

Here is the code used in order to register my CPT and taxonomies :

```
     function ms_register_post_type() {
  $gallery_labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Photographies des membres', 'Post type general name', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Galerie', 'Post type singular name', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
            'menu_name'             => _x( 'Galeries', 'Admin Menu text', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Galeries', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        );
        $gallery_args = array(
            'labels'             => $gallery_labels,
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'photographies','with_front' => false ),
            'capability_type'    => 'page',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => true,
            'menu_position'      => 5,
            'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'post-formats' ),
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-images-alt',
        );
        register_post_type( 'ms_photo_portfolio', $gallery_args );

    }
add_action( 'init', 'ms_register_post_type');
/**
* Register Portfolio taxonomies
*
*
*/
function ms_create_taxonomies() {
    //TAXONOMIE PERSONNALISEE -> CATEGORIES
    $category_labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Th&egrave;mes', 'taxonomy general name', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Th&egrave;me', 'taxonomy singular name', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Rechercher des cat&eacute;gories', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'Toutes les cat&eacute;gories', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Cat&eacute;gorie parente', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Cat&eacute;gorie parente : ', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( '&Eacute;diter la cat&eacute;gorie', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Mettre &agrave; jour la cat&eacute;gorie', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Ajouter une cat&eacute;gorie', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nom de la cat&eacute;gorie', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Th&egrave;mes', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
    );
    $category_args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $category_labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'themes','with_front' => false ),
    );
    register_taxonomy('ms_photo_cat', array('ms_photo_portfolio'), $category_args);
    // TAXONOMIE PERSONNALISEE -> PHOTOGRAPHES
    $photographer_labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Photographes', 'taxonomy general name', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Photographe', 'taxonomy singular name', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Rechercher des photographes', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'Tous les photographes', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Editer le profil', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Mettre &agrave; jour le profil', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Ajouter un profil', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nom du photographe', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Photographes', 'ms-photo-gallery' ),
    );
    $photographer_args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $photographer_labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'membres','with_front' => false ),
    );
    register_taxonomy('ms_photo_author', array('ms_photo_portfolio'), $photographer_args);
     // Color taxonomy (non-hierarchical)
     $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Couleurs',
        'singular_name'              => 'Couleur',
        'search_items'               => 'Rechercher des couleurs',
        'popular_items'              => 'Couleurs populaires',
        'all_items'                  => 'Toutes les couleurs',
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => 'Editer la couleur',
        'update_item'                => 'Mettre &agrave; jour la couleur ',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Ajouter une couleur',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Nom de la couleur',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'S&eacute;parer les couleurs avec des virgules',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Ajouter ou supprimer des couleurs',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choisir parmis les couleurs les plus utilis&eacute;es',
        'not_found'                  => 'Pas de couleur trouv&eacute;e.',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Couleurs',

    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'couleurs','with_front' => false  ),
    );
    // associer cette taxonomie au portfolio et aux m&eacute;dias.
    register_taxonomy( 'ms_photo_color', array( 'ms_photo_portfolio' ), $args );
}
add_action('init', 'ms_create_taxonomies');


/**
* Rewrite Flush
*
*
*/
function ms_rewrite_flush() {
    // First, we "add" the custom post type via the above written function.
    // Note: "add" is written with quotes, as CPTs don't get added to the DB,
    // They are only referenced in the post_type column with a post entry, 
    // when you add a post of this CPT.
    ms_register_post_type();

    // ATTENTION: This is *only* done during plugin activation hook in this example!
    // You should *NEVER EVER* do this on every page load!!
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ms_rewrite_flush' );
```

Thanks in advance for help,

Maral.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the rewrite in your register_taxonomy $args

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'photographies/couleurs','with_front' => false  ),
```

This will probably clash with rewriting the custom post type so you'll more than likely get a 404 on this url: http://thewebsite/photographies/ but if you don't need that url then this solution  will help you get closer to what you want but I'm pretty sure: http://thewebsite/photographies/couleurs/ will always give you a 404 as within a taxonomy you'll need to create terms then you can link to a page with those terms e.g. http://thewebsite/photographies/couleurs/black-and-white.

Comment: I already tried this option and Indeed it crashes. I want to use the slug photographies in order to show all the picture independently of the author, the color or of the category. I just want to nest the taxonomy slug in the URL...I didn't found a solution that's why I'm posting thank you in advance